# replace id wih name in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to replace id with name in different table

[image: this a table i have]

```
SELECT item.item_name FROM item;

SELECT tbl_category.category_name AS parentCategoty 
   FROM tbl_category
   INNER JOIN items 
   ON tbl_category.category_id = items.item_category_id;

SELECT tbl_category.category_name AS subCategoty
   FROM tbl_category 
   INNER JOIN items 
   ON tbl_category.category_id = items.item_sub_category_id;
```

Result:

```
    --------------------------------------------------------
    | item_name |  item_category_id | item_sub_category_id |
    --------------------------------------------------------
    | Tomato    |  food             | vegetables
    | Banana    |  food             | fruit
    | clotes    |  textile          | Uniform
    | Lenovo    |  Electronics      | Laptop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
SELECT i.item_name, c.category_name, sc.category_name FROM item i 
    INNER JOIN category c ON i.item_category_id = c.category_id 
    INNER JOIN category sc ON c.category_id = sc.parent_category_id
```

However, I'll point out that your design appears to be flawed. If a subcategory can identify its parent category through the self-join, there is no need to keep both category_id and sub-category_id in the items table. Item should only relate to sub_category, which will in turn identify its parent through self-join.

Comment: Exactly what is redundant about it?

Comment: there is the same data 4x

Comment: there is data that I did not input carried away